How do I fit a normal distribution to a dirac delta distribution for behavior cloning in reinforcement learning?
I am attempting to apply behavior cloning to actor-critic agents that operate under a continuous action space. I have some dirac delta function is denoted as p_bc(a|x) where a is the action and x is the state. I have a test neural network that represents the actor where it trys to learn some mean, u(x), and sigma, o(x), for a given x. I have tested MSE and NLL as loss functions. I wanted to test KL loss but because I could not find any documentation on dirac delta functions, I am unsure if there is a distribution module in pytorch. Basically, my question is what am I doing wrong and what are some alternatives I could do?
I have some test neural network in pytorch
class DistributionFitModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.model = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(1, 16),
            nn.Linear(16, 32),
            nn.Linear(32, 16)
        )
        
        self.mu = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(16, 1), nn.ReLU())
        self.logvar = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(16, 1), nn.ReLU())
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.model(x)
        mu = self.mu(x)
        logvar = self.logvar(x)
        
        std = torch.exp(0.5 * logvar)
        eps = torch.randn_like(std)
        return eps.mul(std).add_(mu)
    
    def mu_sigma(self, x):
        x = self.model(x)
        return self.mu(x), torch.exp(0.5 * self.logvar(x))

I use logvar instead of var directly because that's what I've seen VAE implementations do
keys = [(0, -1), (1, 1), (2, -1), (3, 0), (4, 1), (5, 0)]
ys = []
xs = []
L = 1000
for x_mul, y_mul in keys:
    ys += (np.ones(1000) * y_mul).tolist()
    xs += (np.ones(1000) * x_mul).tolist()

I generate 1000 samples of a given x and corresponding action (ie x = 0, a = -1 for first key)
I have some dataset/dataloader to load in the generated data
class DistDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.x)
        
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return torch.tensor(self.x[item]), torch.tensor(self.y[item])
dataset = DistDataset(xs, ys)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=512, shuffle=True)

I have the training loop set up as
for _ in range(1000):
    running_loss = 0
    for x, y in dataloader:
        x = x.reshape(-1, 1).float()
        y = y.reshape(-1, 1).float()
        
        pred = model(x).reshape(-1, 1)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss = F.mse_loss(pred, y)
        
        # mu, sigma = model.mu_sigma(x)
        # dist = Normal(mu, sigma)
        # values = dist.log_prob(y)
        # loss += torch.sum(values)
        
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        running_loss += loss.item()
    print(running_loss / len(dataloader))

when I call model.mu_sigma(x), I am getting mu = 0 and sigma = 1 for all the outputs
Is there something I am doing wrong? Is there some better loss function I should be doing?

The first thing is to question whether it truly makes sense to use a gaussian distribution instead of a categorical. If you have decided that yes, that is what you should do... Then simply you have a set of state-action pairs. Your states are your data and your actions are your labels. Use your neural network to draw samples and optimize the binary crossentropy between your output and the label.
The cross-entropy is very much related to the KL divergence. In fact, you can pretend that you are using the KL divergence and just ignore p(x) because your model's parameters do not depend on it and the partial derivative is zero.
Of course since the bottomline is that you want to learn gaussians with a standard deviation of zero, it might not be a fun experiment. To circumvent it, and only if it makes sense within the broad context of your experiment, you can exclude the variance from the learnable parameters. For the purpose of numerical stability, you can treat it as a hyperparameter that you set at a very small value. Then you only have to get your neural network to learn the mean, which should be equivalent to your delta function.
Another thing to consider is whether you assume a high dimensional gaussian with a dimensionality equal to the number of discrete actions, or if you assume independent gaussians for each category. The difference is in whether you wish to model correlations between different actions.

I chose to use a Gaussian distribution because in continuous action spaces the values might not necessarily be (-1, 0, 1). It is a virtual robot that can turn between -90 and 90 degrees. I have done some work on discrete action spaces and was able to learn the distributions but I want to have the accessibility to do both types of action spaces.
I will look into learning just the mean but I wonder how valid of an option that is for behavior cloning.

I am referencing https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.10087 where equation (5) describes the general objective of behavior cloning. I am just not confident in if this is a valid approach and if I were to write a paper on it, I would be able to sufficiently explain my reasoning

I see. A categorical distribution is discrete and might not suit your needs. The problem that I see with a gaussian is that maybe you will have a bimodal distribution and then modelling it with a gaussian will give you high variance with most of the density between the peaks of the distribution that you want to have your algorithm learn. Agree, stackoverflow comments are not the best forum for an in-depth discussion. But I can recommend looking into the concrete distribution (Maddison2016) / gumbel softmax (Jang2016) for a continuous alternative to the categorical distribution.
